# Is there off-the-shelf open source software for generating serial numbers of user-definable number bases?

Tags: perl, license-key

Is there off-the-shelf open source software for generating serial numbers of user-definable number bases?

Preferably in Perl, or similar scripting language.

Comment: You mean like `perl -e 'printf "%0".$ARGV[0]."d\n", $_ for (shift..shift);' 1 10 5`? I hereby license this with the BSD license. Have fun.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [Integer::Tiny](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Integer%3a%3aTiny).  It allows you to specify an arbitrarily-sized string of single-character "digits", then converts integers into that set.  Give it a string of length *n* and the number is effectively converted into base *n* (although it won't look like a normal base *n* representation unless that string orders the digits normally, of course).

**Edit:**  Here's the one-liner base-10 solution from Sorpigal's comment redone in base-3:

```
perl -MInteger::Tiny -e 'my $it = Integer::Tiny->new("012"); printf "%0".$ARGV[0]."d\n", $it->encrypt($_) for (shift..shift);' 1 10 5
```

Comment: +1 Thanks @Dave Sherohman, but is there a limit to the size of the input integer, e.g. 32 bit?

Comment: @Rob: According to the documentation, Integer::Tiny will accept Math::BigInt ("Arbitrary size integer/float math package") objects and I see that there is a check in the I::T source to identify and correctly handle M::BI references, so it should be unlimited in practice, you just need to switch from native integers to M::BI when you exceed the integer size of the system you're running it on.